# Multiple personalities on multiple URLs for my blog

Tags: blogger

I have a blog at blogger. We are using this blog as a communication and knowledge management platform between different boddies of users (closed membership). Every body also has a website with a distinct corporate identity. I would love now to have the blog appear in the local personality for each body. How can I do that?

Since only a few people are authors, the personalities do not really need to have editing facilities (this can be done via email or blogger.com itself).

To react on @TomatoSandwich's comment:

All my blogs have their own url (blog.companyA.ca, blog.companyB.ch). These websites have their own corporate identity (using www.companyA.ca and www.companyB.ch respectively) and the blog should blend in. Posting to one of the blogs should have the post appear on the other one as well.

I know I could do email posting and just have two blogs with two distinct email addresses and a common one that would post to both. I do not like email posting though as most people will use office and html formatted emails - usually not a good idea for size and style reasons.

I would like the editors to be able to go to blogger.com, post in a single spot, and have the entry in multiple blogs.

Comment: Do you mean.. you want to have companyA.blogspot.com appear identical to companyb.blogspot.com? Or have the email postings, etc, be synonymous?

Comment: @TomatoSandwich I hope my edit made the question more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing the cross posting, would be to use a desktop client - BlogJet, Windows Live Writer or BlogDesk. Alternatively you could use firefox plugin like ScribeFire.  Several offer ways select and post to multiple blogs.

It sounded like you were really hoping for a web based solution, so perhaps the Post to My Blog web service mentioned over here would be useful:

http://www.labnol.org/internet/blogging/post-blog-entries-to-multiple-blogging-platforms/4943/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add a feed from another blog (ex: companyB) that would blend in to look exactly like it was posted to your blog (ex: companyA). The official Feed plugin allows you to publish the content of another blog somewhere in your page (wherever you want), but I don't think it can be mixed in (and it might only be the title of those posts with a link to the actual post).